Where all liquidity gone in a Raydium Pool
I purchased tiny amount of CATDRICK token on Raydium.
The pool is created with 200K CATDRICK + 39 SOL.
Here is a Raydium Pool on Solscan.
I filtered for defi activities and token creator added 200K CATDRICK token and 39 SOL.
However when I check the liquidity on dexscreener it only shows $296 worth of liquidity.
If there is a rugpull, why there's no REMOVE LIQUIDITY action shown in solscan?
Thank you
